# Google Oauth 2.0 redirect_uri_mismatch - Port changed on callback

Tags: c#, .net, oauth-2.0

I'm using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync() to authenticated a Google account, the problems is that Google returns a 400 error after I've logged into my Google account:

The redirect URI in the request: http://localhost:40745/authorize/ did not match a registered redirect URI.

But my mvc application runs at 46423, also the Redirect URI is set to http://localhost:46423/authorize/ in the dev console. What am I missing?

Comment: I don't know. I can't see anything. Without any code it's hard to say

Comment: Doesn't Google require https for the redirect URI?

Comment: Turns out I was using the wrong application type in my setup in Google dev console. When I changed to "Installed application" I got the right callback url from google.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The redirect URI changes each time you debug. You should add `http://localhost/authorize/` to your redirect URI list in the Credential page.

Comment: Thank you very much, this works for my but with localhost/Callback

Comment: I had to use `http://127.0.0.1/authorize/` but other than that it worked like a charm!

Comment: This doesn't help because the port is randomized each time, and Google won't accept it without the port included.

Comment: Unbelievably, this works with a trailing slash, but not without, regardless of port.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is at the line `flow.run_local_server(port=0)` of the `quickstart.py` file.

When port=0, the operating system will dynamically assign an available port number, which is useful in cases where the default port is already in use by another process. So you need to change this to say for example `flow.run_local_server(port=8000)` and register in the credentials page.